# Why when uploading via PHP, sender never gets closure (200 header?) and so upload never seems to end

Tags: php, upload, header

I am uploading (POST) a file to my server using php on the server end. The file is uploaded ok but I am expecting that once it has uploaded it displays a bit of text on the screen and that is the end of it.

However the server never seems to tell the sender that the upload has been received and everything is ok. I am assuming its waiting for the 200 header and it never arrives, does that sound likely? What could be causing that?

Comment: Did you check your php configuration ? http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-apache-increase-php-upload-limit/

Comment: Have you used fiddler or similar to look at the request-response? You could then replace that "never seems to" with either "doesn't tell the user-agent" or "the server sends a response but the user-agent acts like it doesn't get it". Not an answer, but might be a step closer to one. (Also +1 just for "never gets closure" making me imagine a web-browser with psychological issues about a failed upload).

Comment: I will look into that Jon, oh and very funny comment, made me laugh too :-)